# Inline-block for search form in Bootstrap 3

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I have the following navbar in my Rails app. I can't figure out why the search button, which is an image, won't stay inline to the right of the search form. I'm sure there is a some parent CSS that is preventing it, but I can figure it out.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <%= link_to "theTens", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
</div> 
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li>    
      <%= link_to 'theReviewers',  reviewers_path %>
    </li>
    <li>    
      <%= link_to 'theComments',  comments_board_path %>
    </li>
    <li>    
      <%= link_to 'theStats',  stats_path %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <form action="/pins" class="form-inline col-xs-12" method="get">
          <input id="search" type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              <%= image_submit_tag("search.png", :name => nil) %>
        </form>  
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> theMenu 
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-toggle"><%= link_to 'Add +',  new_pin_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile',  edit_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Logout',  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
      </ul>  
        <li><%= link_to (image_tag current_user.image(:small), class: "smallpic"), current_user %></li>
        <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Login',  new_user_session_path %></li>
      <% end %>  
    </ul>
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: did you use `pull-right`?

Comment: how about a jsfiddle?